# Know other app start and close

Tags: android

I just want to know how to know an app is started and closed. I just want to find a way that when skype is started, a service on the background will detect it and then automatically start another app to collect the sensor data. Dose anybody have some ideas about that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a job for a Broadcast Receiver.  There's a reasonable explanation [here](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/android-developer-tutorial-part-11.html) - I've never used them, but I was wondering how to do the same thing a week or so back, and half-reading that page is about as far as I got.  If you get it working, please post back here with your results.

Comment: I know boradcast receiver, but it seems for installed app such as, I don't know which intent I need to receive that indicates the skype or some installed app is started